# Reseved vector segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Im trying to reserve memory and copy from Vulkan memory

```
try { 
    image.reserve(a_width * a_height * 4);
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "p     ... " << (a_width * a_height) << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < (a_width * a_height); i += 1)
  {
  std::cout << "q     ... " << i << std::endl;
    image.push_back((unsigned char)(255.0f * (pmappedMemory[i].r)));
    image.push_back((unsigned char)(255.0f * (pmappedMemory[i].g)));
    image.push_back((unsigned char)(255.0f * (pmappedMemory[i].b)));
    image.push_back((unsigned char)(255.0f * (pmappedMemory[i].a)));
  }
```

total size is 7680000
but it stops at 1952768 with Segmentation fault (core dumped)

catch didn't catch anything

Comment: Aside: won't that multiply cause overflow in the unsigned char target?

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), probably as `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: Please add the definition of `image`

Comment: `push_back` won't segfault. If `reserve` succeeded and if your vector is a `std::vector<unsigned char>` then I don't think it's even possible for it to fail (at least on a conforming platform). The problem is likely `pmappedMemory[i]`.

Comment: Check the size of pmappedMemory. You might be trying to index into that which is out of bounds.

Comment: `try` and `catch` won't catch undefined behaviour, since you cannot recover or even end the program when you're in UB land. Once you're in UB there is nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 3):

It stops at almost exactly one quarter of the way. The memory allocated for `pmappedMemory` is simply too small. You probably allocated a number of pixels instead of the right number of elements (four times the pixels)

Another option is that the pmappedbuffer actually contains bytes, and you are mistakenly assuming it is a float buffer. How did you get this mapped area, and what is it pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparantly its an Intel Graphics Vulkan support problem
Cure - map memory by rows